# appengine is not saving

Tags: google-app-engine, go

For some reason nothing gets saved when the test code below is run.  I have other api methods that when run (not through tests, this is just the first test) do save.

When I check the database stats via localhost:8000, it can be seen that nothing is being inserted.

**Update**: After copying and pasting the code below and wrapping it is GET request handler with some hardcoded data it does save to the database.  So this seems like an issue with the testing `aetest.Context` that is used. I have added the code for the `NewTestHandler` helper code.

Method to create the context within the tests

```
func NewTestHandler(handlerFunc func(appengine.Context, http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        c, _ := aetest.NewContext(nil)
        handlerFunc(c, w, r)
    })
}
```

Error (**update**: the key that is generated returns 0 when calling .IntId())

```
// happens in the .Get() error handling
--- err datastore: internal error: server returned the wrong number of entities
```

Model

```
package app

import "time"

type League struct {
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Location  string `json:"location"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
```

Code

```
func (api *LeagueApi) Create(c appengine.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // data
    var league League
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&league)
    defer r.Body.Close()

    // save to db
    key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "leagues", nil)
    if _, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &league); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    var leagueCheck League
    if err := datastore.Get(c, key, &leagueCheck); err != nil {
        log.Println("---  err", err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // json response
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(league); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Test

```
func Test_LeagueReturnedOnCreate(t *testing.T) {

    league := League{Name: "foobar"}
    data, _ := json.Marshal(league)
    reader := bytes.NewReader(data)

    // setup request and writer
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/leagues", reader)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    // make request
    api := LeagueApi{}
    handler := tux.NewTestHandler(api.Create)
    handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)

    // extract api response
    var leagueCheck League
    json.NewDecoder(w.Body).Decode(&leagueCheck)

    if leagueCheck.Name != "foobar" {
        t.Error("should return the league")
    }

    // ensure the league is in the db
}
```

Comment: Using the complete key does seem to retrieve the league, at least according to the log statement, however the database is still empty.  Are records not permanently saved to the db during testing? As for closing the Body, I saw it done in an example somewhere and they stressed its importance, but now I see it is a io.ReadCloser, so you are right :)

Comment: Correct. aetest is meant for unit testing so you create data from a clean slate everytime.